# <1 name, 1 poem, 2 ciphers>

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

```
tibmm!j!dpnqbsf!uiff!up!b!tvnnFs(t!Ebz   
vjqw""Ctv""oqtg""nqxgna""cpF""oqtg""vgorgtcvg<  
urxjk#zlqgv#gr#vkdnh#wkh#gduoLqj#Exgv#Ri#pdb/  
erh$wyqqIv+w$piewi$lexl$epp$xss$wlsvx$e$Hexi>  
xtrjynrj%ytt%mty%ymj%jdj%tk%mjfajs%xmnsjx1  
gtj&ulzkt&oy&Noy&murj&Iusvrkdout&joss-j!  
huk'lClyf'mhpy'Myvt'mhpy'zvtlAptl'kljspUlz3  
jg(kpivkm4(wz(vibczm/A(kpivoqvo(kwczam4(cvbzquu/l#  
kdc)cqh)ncnawju)bdvvna)bqjuu)wxc)ojmn  
xyb*vyco*zyccoccsyx*yp*drkd*pksb*drye*yg1cd%  
yzc+dslww+oples+mclr+Eszf+hlyopc2de+Ty+std+dslop7  
itqz,uz,qfqdzmx,xuzqe,fa,fuyq,ftag,sdai3ef'  
fb-ybat-nf-zra-pna-oerngur-be-rlrf-pna-frr9  
gc.zcbu.zwjsg.hvwg:.obr.hvwg.uwjsg.zwts.hc.hvss<
```

Comment: What are we supposed to find ? the name ? the poem ?

Comment: Both, if you can

Comment: See this [meta post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do/1718#1718) about making a good code puzzle

Answer (score 9):

> Each line is rot-??  from rot25 to rot-12 with different separators
>
>  shall!i!compare!thee!to!a!summEr(s!Day
>  thou""Art""more""lovely""anD""more""temperate< 
>  rough#winds#do#shake#the#darlIng#Buds#Of#may/
>  and\$summEr+s\$lease\$hath\$all\$too\$short\$a\$Date>
>  sometime%too%hot%the%eye%of%heaven%shines1
>  and&often\&is\&His\&gold\&Complexion\&dimm-d!
>  and'eVery'fair'From'fair'someTime'decliNes3
>  by(chance4(or(nature/S(changing(course4(untrimm/d#
>  but)thy)eternal)summer)shall)not)fade
>  nor*lose*possession*of*that*fair*thou*ow1st%
>  nor+shall+death+brag+Thou+wander2st+In+his+shade7 
>  when,in,eternal,lines,to,time,thou,grow3st'
>  so-long-as-men-can-breathe-or-eyes-can-see9
>  so.long.lives.this:.and.this.gives.life.to.thee<

This is

> **Shall I compare thee to a summer’s day?** (Sonnet 18) of William Shakespeare as Paul Evans has mentionned
>
>  Shall I compare thee to a summer’s day?
>  Thou art more lovely and more temperate.
>  Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May,
>  And summer’s lease hath all too short a date.
>  Sometime too hot the eye of heaven shines,
>  And often is his gold complexion dimmed;
>  And every fair from fair sometime declines,
>  By chance, or nature’s changing course, untrimmed;
>  But thy eternal summer shall not fade,
>  Nor lose possession of that fair thou ow’st,
>  Nor shall death brag thou wand’rest in his shade,
>  When in eternal lines to Time thou grow’st.
>       So long as men can breathe, or eyes can see,
>       So long lives this, and this gives life to thee.

Comment: Ah, now it all makes sense! Couldn't figure out why the lonely rot13 sitting there near the end. Well done :)))

Comment: So this is the 1 poem. Any ideas on the 1 name? Probably has to do with the capitalized letters, or perhaps the different word delimiters in each line, or maybe both.

Comment: @ScottM No idea, I tried rot on original capitalized letter and on deciphered ones but nothing.

Comment: Could you put in how much you had to rot each line by? That's also a possible vector for encoding the name.

Comment: @TimC it decreases from 25 for the top line, then 24, 23... until the last line where it is rot12

Comment: A better explanation might be that the alphabet has been shifted forwards 1, 2, 3, etc. The same thing has happened to the punctuation: the ASCII characters after space are !"#$%&'()*+,-. which is why those are the separators.

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer

> rot-13 of second to last line is:
>  "so long as men can breathe or eyes can see".
>  Which is from:
>  Shakespeare's Sonnet 18 - Shall I Compare Thee to a Summer's Day